# GeometryReader in SwiftUI ScrollView causes weird behaviour and random offset

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Im trying to create a ScrollView that in turn contains a GeometryReader (Explicitly not the other way around). The GeometryReader should contain an (image) with a fixed width and height. However when doing this, the ScrollView pushes the view "above" the screen, it seems like it's applying some random vertical offset.

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Image("hp")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 400)
                .clipped()
        }
    }
}
```

When removing the GeometryReader and just inserting the image it works fine.

Can somebody help?

Edit: Found a solution. I achieved the desired behaviour by telling the image that it should be as high and wide as the inner geometry reader. Then i'm setting the inner geometry reader

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { outerGeometry in
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                GeometryReader { innerGeometry in
                    Image("hp")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: innerGeometry.size.width,
                        height: innerGeometry.size.height)
                        .offset(y: innerGeometry.frame(in: .global).minY/7)
                        .clipped()
                }
                    .frame(width: outerGeometry.size.width, height: 300)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GeometryReader`, if placed as you did, provides the size not of `ScrollView` itself, but of "Content View" in which image is placed. "Content View" of `ScrollView` is bigger than screen size, to allow spring effect at the edges, when one scrolls more than a scrolling document size.

The correct usage is in [@Александр_Грабовский's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58966715/881191).

Answer (score 24):

Just try to put `ScrollView` inside `GeometryReader` and not vice versa:

```swift
// ...
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            ScrollView {
                Image("hp")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 400)
                    .clipped()
            }
        }
            
    }
// ...
```

and the result should be:

[image]